# Capitalize strings within tuples in a nested list

Tags: python

I have such a nested list,

```
Keywords_33=[('file', ['with', 'as']),
             ('module', ['from', 'import']),
             ('constant_3', {'bool': ['False', 'True'], 'none': ['None']}),
             ('operator_4',
                      {'boolean_operation': {'and', 'not', 'or'},
                       'comparison': {'is'}}),
             ('sequnce_operation_2', ['in', 'del']),
             ('klass_1', ['class']),
             ('function_7',
                      ['lambda','def','pass',
                       'global','nonlocal',
                       'return','yield']),
             ('controlled_loop', ['while', 'for', 'continue', 'break']),
             ('condition', ['if', 'elif', 'else']),
             ('debug', ['assert', 'raise']),
             ('exception', ['try', 'except', 'finally'])]
```

I intend to capitalize the leading string in each element tuple with the following code:

```
In [40]: list(map(lambda x:x[0].capitalize(), Keywords_33))
Out[40]:
['File',
 'Module',
 'Constant_3',
 'Operator_4',
 'Sequnce_operation_2',
 'Klass_1',
 'Function_7',
 'Controlled_loop',
 'Condition',
 'Debug',
 'Exception']
```

It outputs only parts of the nested list.

My desired output is:

```
Keywords_33=[('File_2', ['with', 'as']),
             ('Module_2', ['from', 'import']),
             ('Constant_3', {'bool': ['False', 'True'],
                             'none': ['None']}),
             ('Operator_4', {'boolean_operation': {'or', 'and', 'not'},
                             'comparison': {'is'}}),
             ('Sequnce_operation_2', ['in', 'del']),
             ('Klass_1', ['class']),
             ('Function_7',['lambda', 'def', 'pass',
                            'global', 'nonlocal',
                            'return', 'yield']),
             ('Repetition_4', ['while', 'for', 'continue', 'break']),
             ('Condition_3', ['if', 'elif', 'else']),
             ('Debug_2', ['assert', 'raise']),
             ('Exception_3', ['try', 'except', 'finally'])]
```

How can I improve it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what your expected output is?

Comment: I take in the expected output. @SudheeshSinganamalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve the whole tuple in your `map`, and then apply `capitalize` to only the first part:

```
list(map(lambda x:(x[0].capitalize(), x[1]), Keywords_33))
```

In my opinion, though, you should avoid `map` and stick with a list comprehension:

```
[(item[0].capitalize(), item[1]) for item in Keywords_33]
```

You can even use unpacking to make this even more elegant:

```
[(keyword.capitalize(), entries) for keyword, entries in Keywords_33]
```